# Python timer in math game Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, timer, tkinter

I'm looking to add a timer for my simple math game. So far everything works just fine, the user gets questions when pressing the button and is given feedback on the answer. I want to add a timer for the user to see how much time it takes to answer the multiplication. This is the final part of my prototype to this mathgame. I want the timer to start when the user clicks "nytt tal" which means new number in swedish, and to stopp when the user clicks "svar" which means answer in swedish. Here is my code.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import random
import time
import sys

# Definition for the question asked to user 
def fraga1():
    global num3 
    num3 = random.randint(1, 10)
    global num4 
    num4 = random.randint(1, 10)
    global svar1 
    svar1 = num3 * num4
    label1.config(text='Vad blir ' + str(num3) + '*' + str(num4) + '?')
    entry1.focus_set()


#The answer giving feedback based on answer
def svar1():
   mainAnswer = entry1.get()
   if len(mainAnswer) == 0:
      tkMessageBox.showwarning(message='Skriv in några nummer!')
   return
   if int(mainAnswer) != svar1:
      tkMessageBox.showwarning(message='Tyvärr det rätta svaret: ' + str(svar1))
   else:
      tkMessageBox.showinfo(message='RÄTT!! :)')

#The quit button definition
def quit():
   global root
   root.destroy()

#Definition for the timer this part doesnt work
def start():
   global count_flag 
   fraga1()
   count_flag = True
   count = 0.0
   while True:
      if count_flag == False:
          break
   label['text'] = str(count)
   time.sleep(0.1)
   root.update()
   count += 0.1


#Window code
root = Tk()
root.title("multiplikations tidtagning")
root.geometry('800x500')

count_flag = True

# Welcome message in labels
label2 = Label(root, text="Hej!\n  Nu ska vi lösa lite matteproblem!")
label2.config(font=('times', 18, 'bold'), fg='black', bg='white')
label2.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Instructions how to play in labels

label3 = Label(root, text="Instruktioner!\n  För att starta ett spel tryck på nyttspel") 
label3.config(font=('times', 12, 'bold'), fg='black', bg='white')
label3.grid(row=2, column=2)

#other label
label1 = Label(root)
label1.grid(row=2, column=0)


# entry widget for the start button
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row=3, column=0)

# restart gives a new question
entry1.bind('', func=lambda e:checkAnswer())

#Buttons

fragaBtn = Button(root, text='Nytt tal', command=fraga1)
fragaBtn.grid(row=4, column=0)

svarButton = Button(root, text='Svar', command=svar1)
svarButton.grid(row=4, column=1)


quit_bttn = Button(root, text = "Avsluta", command=quit)
quit_bttn.grid(row=5, column=0)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello you should look here = > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777643/how-to-stop-a-timer-python I hope it will help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you need is this .

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

class StopWatch(Frame):  
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()               
        self.makeWidgets()      

    def makeWidgets(self):                         
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)                      

    def _update(self): 
        """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))

    def Start(self):                                                     
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:            
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1        

    def Stop(self):                                    
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Reset(self):                                  
        """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        self._start = time.time()         
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)

    Button(root, text='Start', command=sw.Start).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Stop', command=sw.Stop).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Reset', command=sw.Reset).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=LEFT)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

P.S: Fit this in your code I just implemented the basic timer in tkinter.

Comment: This code you've posted, is it supposed to be under the definition for def start() ? Date ofc in the import section

Comment: Yes you can have it in start but then instead of `while True` you need to call the start function again and again ..for printing out the label and refreshing it

Comment: I cant really understand your answer, I've tried it the thing you write but somehow it doesnt add up to me.

Comment: @tusharmakkar08 I think you need to explain what exactly you've added to your code to make the program work better rather than simply answering with a better code solution. Explanations will easily help the questioner to understand what is going on with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

well if you're using a tkinter you're use the function

```
object.after(100, defineFunction)
```

the first parent is the milisecond

this'll apply to python3.x but 2.7 i cant be sure since i dont pratice that format

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable storing current time when person presses start. Then when the user presses svar in your function svar, just fetch current time, substract them from one another and you get time taken, then reset the global var to 0 also and voila, you have the time taken

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest additional solution with threading.

I hold a small timer in one of my projects and it run as a different thread and gets updated each second:

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
timer = tk.Text(root, width=5, height=1)
timer.insert(tk.INSERT, "00:00")
timer.pack()
def show_time():
    start = time.time()
    seconds = 0
    while True:
        if time.time() - start > 1:
            seconds += int(time.time() - start)
            start = time.time()
            cur_index = timer.index(tk.INSERT)
            cur_index = str(int(cur_index[0]) - 1) + cur_index[1:]
            timer.delete(cur_index, tk.INSERT)
            timer.insert(tk.INSERT, str(int(seconds / 60)) + ":" + str(seconds % 60))
            root.update()
thread = threading.Thread(target=show_time)
thread.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use "after".
You create a widget...

```
time = 60 #60 seconds for example
widget = Tkinter.Label().pack()

def count():
    global time
    if time > 0:
       time -= 1
       widget.config(text="Time left: " + str(time))

       widget.after(1000, count)
```

I use python 3x
Sorry