# How do I stop a timer in Python (tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter

My aim is to create a simple timer program. It updates itself constantly until the **stopButton** is pressed. However, I am unsure how to stop the tick function from running so that the timer stays the same once the **stopButton** is pressed.

This is my code so far:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Timer')
root.state('zoomed')

sec = 0

def tick():
    global sec

    sec += 0.1
    sec = round(sec,1)
    timeLabel.configure(text=sec)
    root.after(100, tick)

def stop(): 
    # stop the timer from updating.

timeLabel = tkinter.Label(root, fg='green',font=('Helvetica',150))
timeLabel.pack()

startButton = tkinter.Button(root, text='Start', command=tick)
startButton.pack()

stopButton = tkinter.Button(root, text='Stop', command=stop)
stopButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What would be a possible way of stopping the `tick()` function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have another global that tracks whether you should currently be counting ticks. If you aren't supposed to be counting ticks, just have `tick` do nothing (and not register itself again).

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Timer')
root.state('zoomed')

sec = 0
doTick = True

def tick():
    global sec
    if not doTick:
        return
    sec += 0.1
    sec = round(sec,1)
    timeLabel.configure(text=sec)
    root.after(100, tick)

def stop():
    global doTick
    doTick = False

def start():
    global doTick
    doTick = True
    # Perhaps reset `sec` too?
    tick()

timeLabel = tkinter.Label(root, fg='green',font=('Helvetica',150))
timeLabel.pack()

startButton = tkinter.Button(root, text='Start', command=start)
startButton.pack()

stopButton = tkinter.Button(root, text='Stop', command=stop)
stopButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

There are other structural improvements that could be made (using a class to get rid of the globals) and style improvements (`snake_case` instead of `camelCase`), but this should get you pointed in the right direction...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: this has a design flaw. if you call stop and then call start again before the timer expires the next interval will not be correct period. In fact you may get 2 events instead of 1 so the timing will break. You should use return value to cancel the event

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776718/how-do-i-stop-tkinter-after-function